# Generating Emma report without going into src folder

Tags: java, jar, emma

I have instrumented Emma with my `.jar` file and have `coverage.ec` and `coverage.em` files ready. I want to generate xml report without going into the src folder since I have only `.jar` file with me and the source folder is on the server.

Is there any alternative for this since I am going into the src folder-

```
java emma report -sp ~/testpack/src -Dreport.xml.depth=method -r xml
-in coverage.em -in coverage.ec`
```